# Visual Express 2012 C# Quick Info Full Description Missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Every where I look Quick Info in Visual C# looks something like this:

[image: screen for MS website]

Yet **my** Quick Info box only shows the name/declaration, **without any description**.

[image: my screenshot]

Are longer descriptions cut from the C# Express version? Or am I doing something wrong? XML comments I'm making work as intended, if it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you [alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/258737/alex) and thank you [Hans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant). Both of your answers lead me to my solution. Also thank you for as quickly answering as you did.

**The Road to Solution** (might be useful for some, if not skip to The Solution)**.**

The file Hans mentioned did exist. Also it did for version 4.0. I also tried to install documentation for Visual Express (as per alex's tip) only to find out that Visual Express 2012 installer doesn't have any options during installation (at least not that kind).

C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework also contained v3.5 folder, but there was only a Profile folder and no mscorlib.xml (or other files that v4.5 and v4.0 had).

Realization came when I found out that Unity3d uses Mono equivalent of .Net 3.5 and in the project setting I found that it was setup for .Net 3.5 (if any one is wondering - Visual Studio is used only for coding, Unity compiles everything).

Few hours of searching later I did find the "documentation" for .Net 3.5.

**The Solution**

What is needed is [Microsoft Windows SDK for Windows 7 and .NET Framework 3.5 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3138). The only thing required to check during installation is Developer Tool->Windows Development Tools->.NET Development Tools. All the Quick Infos for C# functions in my project are now showing correctly!

A note: I tried to find mscorlib.xml for .Net 3.5 afterward but no luck, so I don't know where or in what format the XML documentation for .Net 3.5 is kept but I'm happy as long as it works.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the specific framework target and type you selected.  But for a 4.5 desktop app, this information comes from an .xml file, C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\mscorlib.xml.  The relevant part of that file is:

```
   <member name="T:System.DateTime">
     <summary>Represents an instant in time, typically expressed as a date and time of day. </summary>
     <filterpriority>1</filterpriority>
   </member>
```

So check if that file is there.

Answer (score 1):

More likely, the documentation is cut from the express version to reduce the download size. Have you installed documentation with the visual C#?